# Liquibase - fixing non-rerunnable changeset

Tags: liquibase

My `master-changelog.yaml` is like below:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: db_ver_1.0/scripts.yaml
```

And `scripts.yaml` is like below:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/001_table1_create.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/002_table2_create.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/001_function1.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/002_function2.sql
```

For functions, I set `runOnChange:true`, so the same changeset can still be executed when there is change I put in.

But for tables, say `table1` was only created in Dev env, and I then added a column to it, by creating a new changeset having `ALTER TABLE` statement in it, like below:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/001_table1_create.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/002_table2_create.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/001_function1.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/002_function2.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/003_table1_alter.sql
```

And as time goes, the changesets listed in `scripts.yaml` could be very long, and some of the changesets can actually be combined as one (given the changeset has only been deployed into Dev env).

My question is, when I deploy these changes into T/prod envs, what is the best approach, for the above scenario, if I only want to have one `001_table1_create.sql`, instead of `001_table1_create.sql` + `003_table1_alter.sql`? should I create a `db_ver_2.0/scripts.yaml`, and remove `db_ver_1.0/scripts.yaml` from `master-changelog.yaml`, like below:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: db_ver_2.0/scripts.yaml
```

where `db_ver_2.0/scripts.yaml` only has `tables/001_table1_create.sql` (and this file would have the additional column I added)?

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/001_table1_create.sql   #this file has the additional column
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/002_table2_create.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/001_function1.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: functions/002_function2.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's segregate the changes that come with different application versions, and changes that are meant to be specific to certain environments.

Liquibase [promotes](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/best-practices) organizing changelogs by major release and including them in a root changelog as the best practice. Also, [labels](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/labels.html) are typically used to bind changesets to a certain version or feature.

To execute a changeset on a certain environment or on all the environments of a certain tier, or to generate/import the test data, a common pattern is to use [context](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/contexts.html) attribute.

> some of the changesets can actually be combined as one (given the changeset has only been deplopyed into Dev env)

This actually should be avoided because the changesets ideally should be independent and reversible. You can deploy, rollback, or redeploy a changeset, but not its part. That's why it's recommended to define only one change per changeset unless several changes should be combined in a transaction.